# What is the oci equivalent to sqlsrv_has_rows?

Tags: php, oracle

In PHP, is there equivalent functionality to sqlsrv_has_rows?

I don't want to know how many rows, just has it got any at all.

I don't really want to fetch a row, as that puts the row pointer out.

Comment: [The manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-num-rows.php)

Comment: ha ha - very funny - already looked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no equivalent.  You have to fetch the first row.  If you want to then start at the first row again, you would have to use oci_execute again.  Not a great idea if the query takes a long time to run.

So some logic to store the first row would be a likely route to go down.

Comment: oci_num_rows does not work for selects, only for inserts, updates, etc.  I get a value of 1 if it has one row or zero rows.  From that same manual page:     `Note:This function does not return number of rows selected!`